# Windows 7 restores date and time to current date after set to prior date

Tags: windows-7

I have to set a Windows 7 x64 to a prior date (a few days back from now).

I have done the following:

- Disabled automatic sync with an internet time provider
- Unplugged the network cable

After setting to the prior date, it stays for *exactly 5 seconds* on that date and then it is *restored to current date*.

How can I set it permanently?

Comment: Try disabling the Windows Time service.

Comment: Have you tried setting the date in the BIOS? See if that changes anything.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that.